# Is a Challenge question acceptable here?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

I want to ask a bit of a fun challenge question. It involves some hefty math and probably a lot of speculation. My worry is there is no clear answer. In short, I want to ask how much ice from Europa would cost, per pound, if we were to import it.

If not here, is there another place that would be better suited for it?

Comment: I wonder if worldbuilding would be more appropriate, where speculative science and magnitude-of-order answers are more welcome?

Answer (score 3):

> My worry is there is no clear answer.

Then no. Questions should have a definitive answer and should not be primarily opinion based or solicit prolonged discussion. OK, granted, sometimes it can't be expected of those asking questions to anticipate these problems, but in your case, you seem to already suspect it wouldn't be a great fit for us. From what little you let on about it here, I also suspect it would be too broad. But I'd have to see it to make my mind up.

As for challenges, well, maybe. But it would somewhat stretch our Q&A format thin and you'd have to set exact rules within it that would still fit it. I personally don't like the idea. All questions should be challenging to answer to the best of one's abilities, and to also *[pay it forward](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)*, anyway. If that's not the case, then questions might be too trivial, with readily available answer a simple web search away, and with it failing our *[prior research](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)* requirement.

But don't take my opinion on it as a final ruling on the matter. Perhaps you could make it work. Just make sure you keep your question on-topic, that it won't require too long or opinion based answers, will fit our Q&A format with best answers being highest rated, most useful answer (if any) accepted, and that the whole thread won't go stale as soon as you do that. In other words:

> #### How do I ask a good question?
>
> We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer,
> here are some tips:
>
> **[Search](https://space.stackexchange.com/search), and research**
>
> Have you [thoroughly searched for an answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/search) before asking your
> question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found
> and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken
> the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious
> answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant
> answer!
>
> **Be on-topic**
>
> Our community is defined by a specific set of topics that you [can view
> in the help center](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic); please stick to those topics and [avoid asking for
> opinions or open-ended discussion](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). If your question is about the site
> itself, ask on our [meta-discussion site](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/). If you’re looking for a
> different topic, it might be covered on another [Stack Exchange site](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questions).
>
> **Be specific**
>
> If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer. But if you
> give us details and context, we can provide a useful answer.
>
> **Make it relevant to others**
>
> We like to help as many people at a time as we can. Make it clear how
> your question is relevant to more people than just you, and more of us
> will be interested in your question and willing to look into it.
>
> **Keep an open mind**
>
> The answer to your question may not always be the one you wanted, but
> that doesn’t mean it is wrong. A conclusive answer isn’t always
> possible. When in doubt, ask people to cite their sources, or to
> explain how/where they learned something. Even if we don’t agree with
> you, or tell you exactly what you wanted to hear, remember: we’re just
> trying to help.

So if you think you can satisfy all these requirements, which are otherwise fairly simple to follow if one abides to the Q&A format of ours and asks honest questions, then go for it.

> If not here, is there another place that would be better suited for
> it?

I don't know. You could try in [our main chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9682/the-pod-bay). Or here in [our meta](http://meta.space.stackexchange.com), where [it wouldn't be unheard of](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/461/competition-sexiest-space-exploration-hardware-of-2013) that we setup some fun *challenges* on occasion, for some of which yours truly might have been guilty of. But our main site probably wouldn't be a suitable place for it. And I can't think of any other Stack Exchange site. But [do check](http://stackexchange.com/sites).

Comment: The only place I can think of is possibly the math stack, since it is quite a bit of calculation, but also requires some research on the part of space travel in 2015.

Comment: Well, Europa ice has one big attribute that makes it valuable to a customer: The fact that it's from Europa. Exclusivity sells, especially to rich people lol

Comment: That's what I was thinking