# Is this alright as a Community Ad? Any other proposals?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

For a while we posted Community Ads on other Stack Exchange sites to boost our traffic a bit. The original ones, from [this post](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/364/4660) can no longer be used because the size has changed, and for the most part we don't have the files anyhow.

I was able to get versions of the previous ones from TildalWave and I modified two to create something that fits the new format.

[image: the outer planets, dawn on Earth, and trajectory drawings]

Will this do? Does anyone feel like making up others?

In the interest of democratic process, I posted this here before unilaterally using it as an ad promoting us on other Stack Exchange sites. So, there is also the question of where to post it. I am thinking Science Fiction & Fantasy and Physics. I shall wait a day or two more before going ahead...

Comment: It's a pity it can't be [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MAW2lygZC_4)

Comment: @Machavity It would be horrible if SE allowed video ads.

Answer (score 3):

The user Valorum on Sci-fi and Fantasy has proposed his own adaptation of the above. It’s a bit of a variation on an older ad design and looks quite interesting, in my opinion. If people here like it it can be upvotes, otherwise it could be downvoted (or ask to be removed). The link to the answer is [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11723/20774), and the image is below:

[image: Space SE as proposed by Valorum]

Comment: I didn't do it this way because to me the stretched planets look funny, but it does hang together better. By the way, please thank Valorum.

Comment: Hmm you’re right, it does look a bit stretched, I hadn’t noticed, I will try and see if I can “design” something tonight

Comment: Okay, for those who may not know, this is now posted on  [Science Fiction and Fantasy Meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11723/39126). Thanks to Valorum, a highly active member there, for improving the design.

Answer (score 1):

Having the galactic plane nicely perpendicular to the ecliptic (rather than oblique) opens the site up to ridicule by "sticklers" everywhere, I hope that won't reappear, no matter how nice it looks!

**below:** From the nicely written [Did Earth cross the galactic equator in 2012?](http://earthsky.org/astronomy-essentials/will-earth-pass-through-galactic-plane-in-2012).

[image]

Comment: There are few, few sticklers quite like you uhoh. Your vigilance is impressive.