# Do we have a 300x300 logo that we can use for ads on other stack exchanges?

Tags: discussion

This stack exchange is advertised here: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4675/science-stack-exchanges-helping-other-science-stack-exchanges, but the size is a little bit different from all the other SE's advertised there. Can someone switch it so that our logo is the same size as all the other ones?

Answer (score 3):

Tildal was the one who made our original ads, and he is no longer with us. If someone would like to make a replacement ad, they are welcome.

The thread to submit the ad for community approval is here:

[Ideas for off-site Space Exploration community promotion ads](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/364/58)

Comment: Undo also made an ad that we used but he no longer has the assets to update it.